# How to use L298N motor driver with battery

Tags: motor-controller, l298

I connected L298N motor driver (https://www.itead.cc/wiki/MotoMama) to 4x AA batteries in series (6V) connecting battery holder's positive terminal to Vsupply and negative terminal to GND which is under Vsupply in datasheet. Mentioned setup is illustrated on image below:

[image]
Apparently the result was short circuit. As a result batteries heated up and started to smoke. If I connect it the same way now, nothing happends - probably something broke inside the driver.

Could someone explain me what would be the correct way to setup above mentioned motor driver with 2 DC motors and battery holder for testing without a microcontroller (e.g. Arduino)?

Comment: `result was short circuit` ... how do you know this?

Comment: Batteries heated up and started smoking :) If I now connect it the same way, nothing happens.

Comment: yup, that sounds like a short circuit ... were the batteries oriented correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to comply to the specification given in the  link you provided (see Electrical Characteristics below).

So,

- connect logic power supply to the +5V and GND on the left side of the board
  Not connecting a supply (so, 'connecting 0V') conflicts with the lower limit of 4.5V.
- increase the motor power supply (it should be higher than 7V).
  It now is about 6V, which conflicts with the minimal required 7V.

[image]

Comment: It worked. Thank you a lot :). I thought that +5V is meant for output as was stated in some articles. Could you please explain me for what this +5V is used for. Is it used to power logic circuitry?

Comment: @user3861781 Yes, the 5V is for the logic circuitry. According the L298 datasheet: "An additional supply input is provided so that the logic works at a lower voltage"